# "would" after "if" - "If you would just tell me, it would be easier for the both of us"

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, conditionals, if, would

"If you would just tell me, it would be easier for the both of us"
Why is there "would" after "if"? It has to be an exception because normally you can't do it.

Comment: You say *why is there "if" after "would"* in the body and *"would" after "if"* in the heading. There are two instances of would in the sentence, so maybe you could explain which you want rid of.

Comment: @StuartF Of course, I mean the first "would"

Comment: There is no "if" after either "would". can you clarify. Is "if" a typo for "it" in your question? i.e. "Why is there 'it' after 'would'".

Comment: @timchessish Oh, right, it's a typo. I fixed it

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So in this sentence "would" is not a modal verb but an ordinary verb?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'normally you can't do it'. _If only you would..._ and _if you would just..._ are perfectly normal ways to express a wish that someone would do something which they seem reluctant to do.

Comment: @KateBunting There is a rule that you can't normally use "would/will" in "if clause". There might be exceptions of course

Comment: I'm not aware of such a rule. Do you consider [all these examples](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+you+would+only%2C+if+you+would+just&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) to be exceptions?

Comment: @KateBunting Either exceptions or mistakes. It's a well-known rule. You can find it in many grammar books.

Comment: It _would have been_ good if you had provided a link to one of these 'many books'! However, I now realise that you mean [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if) - "We use _would_ in the main clause, not the conditional clause". However, the use of _would_ for politeness is different - see [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451800/usage-of-if-you-would)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149703/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-kyamond).

Comment: @KateBunting English Grammar In Use is one of the books that say that you can't usually say "would" after "if": "We do not usually say ‘if … would’. We use would (’d) in the other part of the sentence: If I were rich, I would travel a lot. (not If I would be rich)"

Comment: That's quite correct, of course. I hadn't thought of it as a 'rule' because native speakers pick up these things instinctively.  Nevertheless, it's also quite correct to say politely "If you would kindly come this way...", or exasperatedly "If you would only listen, I will tell you...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cambridge Grammar of English:

> Modal verbs (most typically will or would) may occur in conditional clauses if they have a **meaning of willingness** or prediction, or where it is important to mark politeness:

> If *you’ll* wait a minute, I’ll fetch the porter to help you.
> If you *would* all follow me, I’ll show you to your rooms.
> If you *would* have allowed them more time, I still think they would have done
> better.
> (if you had been willing to allow them more time)

OP's sentence: *If you would just tell me, it would be easier for the both of us*

If we take ***would*** there having a meaning of willingness, then the possible paraphrase is:

*If you were just willing to tell me, it would be easier for the both of us.*

Comment: So in polite requests: If you will -> if you are willing to. If you would -> if you were willing to ?

Comment: @Kyamond Yes, it has that meaning.

Comment: This is not right"If you would have allowed them more time, I still think they would have done better".  It's: If you **had allowed them more time**, I still think they **would have** done better.

Comment: And: If you follow me, I'll show you to your rooms. No need for will. Only the first sentence is correct.

Comment: If you’ll wait a minute, I’ll fetch the porter to help you. Correct. For willingness. The other do not work.

Comment: "If you would all follow me..." is fine as a polite request.

Comment: @KateBunting Sure, Kate, sure, But the main thing is that the answer chosen is really "off". Why is it that whenever a conditional appears, people feel obliged to cover every aspect of if whether relevant to the question or not?

Answer (score 1):

Question:

"If you would just tell [or told me] me, it would be easier for the both of us" Why is there "would" after "if"? It has to be an exception because normally you can't do it.

Answer: Because the sentence is grammatically poor.

Compare:

There is no need at all for the first *would*.

"**If you just tell me**, it **would be easier** for the both of us".

The conditional nature of the sentence is maintained. People just throw *would* in all over the place and it just does not stick. [joke]

This is a mixed conditional as the present tense is used in the first clause and would in the second.

A standard conditional would be:    **If you tell me, it will be easier for both of us.**
OR:    **If you told me, it would be easier for both of us**.

Comment: That makes sense. I thought it was an exception. The sentence comes from the game "Ace attorney"

Comment: @Lambie Hi! I hope you are fine! I upvoted your good answer! English is not my mother language. I will never be fluent in English like you!

Comment: @Kyamond Often, the kids who write these games are clueless and you have chosen a mistaken answer.

Comment: @Lambie Well, the quotes from Cambridge Grammar of English sound convincing and I remembered a quote from Practical English Usage: "If you will/would... can be used in polite requests."

Comment: @Kyamond Yes, but that is not relevant here. The answer  you chose has two incorrect sentences. But I guess substandard English doesn't phase you...would and would in a conditional is just about the worst faux-pas one can make. Really awful. "If you would have allowed them more time, I still think they would have done better." That should be: If you had allowed them. No reason for would there.  Two woulds make a pile of doodoo, [ha ha].

Comment: Polite, of course: If you will serve the tea, we can begin. If you would open the door, we could begin. But no would and would.

Comment: @Lambie I don't get why you consider these sentences incorrect when two english grammar books say that you can use "if ... will/would" in polite requests. And every sources I've read say that you can use "would" in the other clause. Practical English Usage gives even an example with two "would": "I would be grateful if you would send me information about the regulations for admission to the Hall School of Design. "

Comment: @Kyamond I am NOT objecting to the Polite Use: I am objecting to would would here: If you would have allowed them more time, I still think they would have done better. There is no reason for it! No reason. It is clearly: If you had allowed them more time=that is not the thing your practical English usage is pointing out. The problem is that you are having trouble with what is and isn't polite usage. If you had allowed them more time does not require willingness.

Comment: Quote “If you would all PLEASE take your seats, we would actually be able to get started on time for once.” Non-native speakers should probably not attempt this. Unquote https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427103/can-would-be-used-twice-in-an-english-conditional-sentence-and-still-be-gramma And for willingness: I would give it a shot if you would like me to.

Comment: @Lambie I think we approach grammar differently. You wrote "There is no reason for it! No reason. It is clearly". If you say "Tell me the time, please", it is clearly that you ask for time but still you can say "Sorry to bother but would you mind telling me the time, please".

Comment: @Lambie "Non-native speakers should probably not attempt this" sorry but you don't have more authority in the number of grammatical structures allowed from the mere fact that you are a native speaker

Comment: @Lambie Also "akwardness" of sentences is subjective. English doesn't have rules what is akward and what is not.

Comment: @Kyamond "English doesn't have rules **about** what is awkward." No, but **there is plenty of ***tradition*** and lots of English editing. Plus, there are mixed conditionals. 
 https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/conditionals-third-mixed. https://www.writing.northwestern.edu/resources-fixing-problems-that-lead-to-awkward-sentences/ "Fixing problems that lead to awkward sentences".