# Usage of Will/Would with the conditional clause

Tags: conditional-constructions, will-would

Occasionally, we have the occurrence of will/would in the condition clauses. In the below examples, 'will' and 'would' are supposed to have the meaning of 'willing to" or 'want to.'

Example 1. If John **will** meet us at the hotel, it will save us a lot of time (first conditional)
Example 2. If you **would** all stop talking, I will continue with the class. (first conditional)

My question: Even if 'would' has a meaning of 'willing to,' should it be used **only in the past?**  If not, suppose somebody is reporting the example 2 later. What would the reported speech be like?

Thanks,
brp7

Comment: No. In (2), the teacher is asking the class top stop talking _now_.

Comment: The habit meaning of 'will' for in the present time. The habit meaning of 'would' is for the past.

Comment: I have found multiple sources that list 'willing to do' as one of the meanings of 'would' in the present. It is weird. For some meanings, 'would' is to be used in the past - and will for the present - and for others, would is for the present as well. 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would

Comment: You are correct about the 'habit' meaning, but this isn't it. See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343927/would-after-if-if-you-would-just-tell-me-it-would-be-easier-for-the-both) (first answer).

Comment: Perhaps similar to this type of meaning: "In English, we often use the past tense (i.e. past simple, past continuous, past perfect, would and could) to express a 'hypothetical' meaning.  Hypothetical, in linguistic terms, means talking about an imaginary, unrealistic or possible (perhaps in another context, but not right now) situation." - buildingblocksenglish.com